# Include a jquery plugin in a rails app: styling isn't applied

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for advice on how to get a jquery plugin to work with a rails app.  Specifically I'm trying to run the below plugin but I would also appreciate general advice on how to get the job done.  it seems like you you may have to require it in application.js and put it in the vendor/assets/javascript directory?  Am I missing anything else?

I can't get this jquery plugin to work in my rails app https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Minimal-jQuery-Count-Up-Plugin-CoutUpCircle.html

I've never installed a plugin before but I downloaded the jquery.countupcircle.min.js file and placed it in 'vendor/assets/javascripts'

in 'app/assets/javascripts' I updated application.js below (should I have another one of these files in vendor/assets/javascripts?)

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery3
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.countupcircle.min
//= require popper
//= require turbolinks
//= require tether
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

on my page I have

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="count-box">19</div> 
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#count-box').CountUpCircle({
    duration: 500, // In ms, default: 5000
    opacity_anim: false,
    step_divider: 1
    });
    });
    </script>

  </div>
</div>
```

the number counts up on the page and I see "19" but no circle and no styling is applied either.

in my styles.css file I have

```
  #count-box {
    display: block;
    border: 2px #ccc solid;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 4em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    line-height: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Comment: Any clue in the browser console?, if you've added the js file to the javascripts folder then you don't need to specify it with require, it'll be added through the require_tree.

Comment: I'm not sure what was up with that plugin, I tried another one and it worked just fine.  btw the require_tree doesn't seem to work when 'vender/assets/javascripts' is used, it only seems to work without using 'require' when i put the plugin in 'app/assets/javascripts' .  So basically with 'vender/assets/javascripts' you need to require it in application.js but you don't have to require it in 'app/assets/javascripts'

Comment: You must place your files in the app/assets/javascripts directory. Files in vendor folder aren't integrated that way. Can you corroborate that?

Comment: 'vender/assets/javascripts' was intended to separate third-party plugins and 'app/assets/javascripts' is for your own scripts correct?  When I place the script under vender/assets/javascripts it will not execute unless I do a "//= require plugin_name" in application.js, however if you wanted to mix all your third-party and custom scripts in app/assets/javascripts then it would work without have to require it in application.js.  It's just up to you if you want to logically separate them out or not to keep the Rails suggested file structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try running rake assets:precompile and restart the server.
If still not working bootstrap is overriding your plugin classes.
Try 
`//= require jquery.countupcircle.min`
After you require bootstrap